# NHibernate - mapping connection-table & back-references

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

Hey, 
I have to map the following entities:

```
class Document
{
   public int DocumentId { get; set; }
   public DocumentList ContainingList { get; set; }
}

class DocumentList
{
   public int DocumentListId { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }
   public IList<Doucment> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

With the constraint that only *one* DocumentList can own a specific document (altough a collection-table exists here).

Mapping has to rely on the following tables (which cannot be changed, for the sake of simplicity):

```
TB_DOC
------
DOC_ID (int, PK)
DOC_CONTENT (blob)

TB_DOC_LIST
-----------
DOC_LIST_ID (int, PK)
DOC_LIST_UPDATE_TIME (datetime)

TB_LIST_AND_DOCS
----------------
DOC_LIST_ID
DOC_ID
```

So the mapping i tohught of would be like this:

```
enter code here

<class name="DocumentList" table="TB_DOC_LIST">
  <id name="DocumentListId">
    <column name="DOC_LIST_ID"/>
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>
  <property name="LastUpdateTime" column="DOC_LIST_UPDATE_TIME ">
  <set name="Documents" table="TB_LIST_AND_DOCS">
    <key column="DOC_ID"></key>
    <one-to-many class="Document" />
  </set>
 </class>
```

and:

```
 <class name="Document" table="TB_DOC">
   <id name="DocumentId">
     <column name="DOC_ID"/>
     <generator class="assigned" />
   </id>

   [ ??? ] - property to reference the "owner" document list

 </class>
```

Now, following the known patterns, i can't figure out how should the back-link from Document to the DocumentList be mapped, since i have a "weired| one-to-many relation here, broken by a third table. 
I also don't want a Document object to reference an IList to solve this with back-referencing many-to-many, since each Document has only one such "owner" DocumentList.
Any elegant idea? what am i mispercepting here?

Answer (score 0):

cant test it right now, but a join could be used to get the reference id.

```
<class name="Document" table="TB_DOC">
  <id name="DocumentId">
    <column name="DOC_ID"/>
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>

  <join table="TB_LIST_AND_DOCS">
    <key column="DOC_ID"/>
    <many-to-one class="DocumentList">
      <column name="DOC_LIST_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
  </join>

</class>
```